# get last record in each group count

Tags: mysql, laravel

How can I get the count of last records of one to many relationship

shipment

| id | bill |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2222 |
| 2 | 4255 |

shipment_status

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | created |
| 1 | Shipped |
| 2 | created |
| 2 | Shipped |
| 2 | Delivered |
| 3 | created |
| 3 | Shipped |
| 4 | Created |
| 4 | Shipped |
| 4 | Delivered |
| 5 | Created |

What I want to get

Results

| count | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Shipped |
| 2 | Delivered |
| 1 | Created |

What I've done :

```
SELECT  a.status, 
        b.total_status 
FROM    hipmenthistories a 
INNER JOIN (  
             SELECT status, 
                    MAX(created_at) last_status,
                    COUNT(*) total_status  
             FROM shipmenthistories
             GROUP   BY status 
            ) b ON a.status = b.status`
```

Comment: Do you have current query?

Comment: `SELECT  a.status, b.total_status`
`FROM    shipmenthistories a`
 `INNER JOIN`
 `(`
` SELECT  status, MAX(created_at) last_status,COUNT(*) total_status`
` FROM    shipmenthistories`
`GROUP   BY status`
` ) b ON  a.status = b.status`

Comment: this return a total status on the table not only the last

Comment: I don't see `created_at` on your table description

Comment: Without an intrinsic descriptor of sequence this is impossible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the desired solution is impossible given the available information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  MySQL 8 you can use the window function ROW_NUMBER

The relevant Part is the ORDER BY FIELD to get the last

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `status` VARCHAR(9)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `status`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'created'),
>   ('1', 'Shipped'),
>   ('2', 'created'),
>   ('2', 'Shipped'),
>   ('2', 'Delivered'),
>   ('3', 'created'),
>   ('3', 'Shipped'),
>   ('4', 'Created'),
>   ('4', 'Shipped'),
>   ('4', 'Delivered'),
>   ('5', 'Created');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `status`, COUNT(*)
> FROM
> (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `id` ORDER BY FIELD(`status`, 'created','Shipped','Delivered') DESC) rn
> FROM table1) t1
> WHERE rn = 1
> GROUP BY `status`
> ```
>
> ```
> status    | COUNT(*)
> :-------- | -------:
> Shipped   |        2
> Delivered |        2
> Created   |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=968028b187b428f09ca73f7caad394bd)*

Comment: when I run it I get the total status
Shipped - 4
created -5

Comment: with the data you privided this works, and is correct, if you have a different dqata set show it i a fiddle.

Comment: also you need the where clause rn = 1 tp only select the last, please read alswayss the complete sql statemenst and copy it correctly

Comment: Here are some of actual data[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd4995c19e5731aab81e564bb586fecf)

Comment: @Heshanmax ask another question and the data in the fiddle post as text on the question itself

Comment: @Heshanmax see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8f613ccbcf536a1721b7a7757a7ac79